# Can an isolated point of E be a limit point of E?

Tags: real-analysis

Here is Rudin's definition of an isolated point $p$ (page 32):

If $p \in E$ and $p$ is not a limit point of $E$, then $p$ is called an isolated point of $E$. Ok, from this I understand that an isolated point of $E$ cannot be a limit point of $E$.

However, later in the book there is a discussion about the continuity of a function at an isolated point $p$. We see that any function defined on a set $E$ will be continuous at an isolated point $p$ in $E$, since for all $\epsilon>0$ you can find a $\delta >0$ such that the only point $x \in E $ for which $d_X(x,p)<\delta$ is where $x=p$, which means that $d_Y(f(x), f(p)) = 0 <\epsilon$.

But my confusion starts with the Theorem that comes right after this (page 86, Theorem 4.6), which states:

> In the situation given above, assume also that $p$ is a limit point of $E$. Then $f$ is continuous at $p$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to\ p}f(x) = f(p)$.

What happened here? Must we assume that $p$ is both a limit point and isolated point of $E$?

Thanks.

Comment: The assumption '$p$ is a limit point of $E$' is made such that '$\lim_{x\to p}f(x)$' makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood.  The book is simply discussing how continuity works in two different cases, depending on whether $p$ is an isolated point or a limit point.  We are not assuming that "$p$ is both a limit point and isolated point", since it is impossible by definition for any one point to be both.

First, if $p$ is an isolated point, then $f$ is automatically continuous at $p$.

Otherwise, if $p$ is a limit point (i.e. not an isolated point), then there is further discussion of what it means to be continuous **in this case**.  In particular, **in this case** we have the result that $f$ is continuous at $p$ if and only if $\lim_{x \to p} f(x) = f(p)$.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. That really cleared up a lot of things for me.

Comment: Why is isolated point continuous? Isn't there are gap between isolated point and its closest point?

Comment: @user13985: Yes, and that's why it works.  It's true that if $p$ is an isolated point, then every function $f$ is continuous at $p$; the proof is given in the question.

Comment: I'm thinking continuity in terms of epsilon-delta neighborhoods. A function like f(k)=1/k, for k=1, 2, 3,... have isolated points, but clearly not continuous.

Comment: @user13985: If you're considering that as a function on the metric space $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ with its natural discrete metric, then that function **is** continuous.  Check the definition!